# Convert input of an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, anonymous-function

I have an anonymous function `A` taking two arguments. I need to convert this function so it takes one argument, by changing the other argument to a constant.

For example having a function:
`A = @(X, Y) X + Y;`
I would like now to have:
`B = @(Y) 3 + Y;`

This seems to be a normal thing to do in mathematics, so I guess there is a way to do such thing in MATLAB. I cannot find the solution though.

The reason I need to do something like this is that I have a function that does some calculations on `A`, but also needs to solve problems when one of the `A`'s arguments is constant. For example find a minimum of the `A` for `X = 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same anonymous function and put `X` as `3` in it but if you want to create another anonymous function, here is how to do that:

```
A = @(X, Y) X + Y;   
B = @(Y) A(3,Y);     %Here you have put X=3
```

To verify:

```
>> A(3,4)

ans =

     7

>> B(4)

ans =

     7
```

Comment: That explains why there is no built-in function. I like it, very clever