# How to assign values to variables in a handle function?

Tags: matlab, function, variable-assignment, function-handle

This is simplified but take as an example the following MATLAB function handle:

```
F = @(x)[x(1)-x(2);x(2)-x(3)]
```

The system has of course has many solutions. Is it possible to obtain a solution for a function like this one after substituting at least one variable? For example, substituting `x(3)=1` the function would become:

```
G = @(x)[x(1)-x(2);x(2)-1]
```

And a solution for the other variables can be obtained. I use `fsolve` and it works quite well for the system of equations I have. Of course what I need to do can be done using the Symbolic Toolbox, but calling it in a big for loop makes it too slow to use for my code.

I'm trying to come up with some code that can return `G` given `F` and a set of indices in `x` to replace with given values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert input of an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486471/convert-input-of-an-anonymous-function)

Comment: Nice example. Almost what I need to do. The difference is that to evaluate F I use x, which is a vector. Can this be done with vectors? Think of the following function:

   `function G = convert (F, x, xMatrix)`
Where xMatrix states which variables are to be substituted. For example if x=[3,2,1] and xMatrix=[0,0,1] that means G will be

    `G = @(x)[x(1)-x(2);x(2)-1]`
Can this be done?

Comment: @SardarUsama: It's more complicated than that, since it's replacing indexed elements in the argument as opposed to replacing an entire input argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're basically asking to do is have `G` call `F` with values in `x` reassigned based on a logical replacement index `index` and a set of replacement values `values`, which is doable but messy since [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) can only have a single executable statement.

The solution is similar to what is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628885/52738), but instead of using the functional form for subscripted reference we'll need to use the functional form for subscripted assignment: [`subsasgn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html). Here's what it would look like:

```
F = @(x)[x(1)-x(2); x(2)-x(3)];
values = [3 2 1];
index = logical([0 0 1]);
G = @(x) F(subsasgn(x, struct('type', '()', 'subs', {{index}}), values(index)));
```

And here's a test:

```
>> F([3 2 3])

ans =

     1
    -1

>> F([3 2 1])  % Replace the last element by 1

ans =

     1
     1

>> G([3 2 3])  % G handles replacing the last element by 1

ans =

     1
     1
```

Comment: This work perfectly. It is fast and fsolve doesn't solve for the substituted values, which is exactly what I needed. Might be messy (it's not easy to understand) but it looks efficient. Great programming skills!
Million thanks.

Comment: @ser: Happy to help! Don't forget you can [mark answers as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).